# How to fill the area below a path in Quartz 2D?

Tags: ios, quartz-2d, fill, area, bezier

I am using Quartz 2D in a UIView object to draw several curves, like this example:

[image: Two curves drawn using Quartz 2D with <code>CGContextStrokePath</code>]

This is the code I have right now (I have omitted the calculation of control points and other stuff):

```
for (int i = 1; i < points.count; ++i) {
  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, previousXValue, previousYValue);
  CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context,
    firstControlPointXValue, firstControlPointYValue,
    secondControlPointXValue, secondControlPointYValue,
    xValue, yValue
  );

  // CGContextFillPath(context);
  CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Now I would like to fill the area below the curve, but if I use `CGContextFillPath` the result is the following:

[image: Two curves filled using Quartz 2D with <code>CGContextFillPath</code>]

which makes sense, because according to [Quartz 2D documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html):

> *When you fill the current path, Quartz acts as if each subpath contained in the path were closed. It then uses these closed subpaths
>   and calculates the pixels to fill.*

Then I tried to move the path to the lower right corner and close the path, but the fill method doesn't have any effect:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

How could I fill the whole area below the curve and not just the subarea closed in every subpath?

#### EDIT:

I have found a temporary solution: drawing a shape using the curve and two vertical lines on each subpath:

```
for (int i = 1; i < points.count; ++i) {
  // Draw the curve
  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, previousXValue, previousYValue);
  CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context,
    firstControlPointXValue, firstControlPointYValue,
    secondControlPointXValue, secondControlPointYValue,
    xValue, yValue
  );
  CGContextStrokePath(context);

  // Draw a shape using curve's initial and final points
  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, previousXValue, rect.size.height);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, previousXValue, previousYValue);
  CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context,
    firstControlPointXValue, firstControlPointYValue,
    secondControlPointXValue, secondControlPointYValue,
    xValue, yValue
  );
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, xValue, rect.size.height);
  CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

I don't know if this is overkill, so improvements are also welcomed. Besides, I'm getting this result:

[image: Two curves drawn using Quartz 2D with the area below them filled]

Note that vertical lines appear as a result of drawing the subareas next to each other. How can that be avoided?

Comment: In addition to my suggestion below, you might be able to also replace `CGContextFillPath` with `CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);` (making sure to set both fill and stroke colors before you start). I prefer the single path technique (you're assured that you'll have a single fill region) I outline below, but this might also do it.

Comment: Can you help me with what I should give to the x and y values in CGContextAddCurveToPoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is right, but you should not fill the individual curves, but rather, create a single path and then fill that. So, start with `CGContextMoveToPoint` to the lower left corner, `CGContextAddLineToPoint` to your first point, do the `CGContextAddCurveToPoint` for all of the curves, and at the end, do a `CGContextAddLineToPoint` to the lower right corner (and you might as well do a `CGContextClosePath` for good measure).

This is a simplified example, where I just have an array of points, but it illustrates the idea:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (!self.points)
        [self configurePoints];

    DataPoint *point;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGColorRef color = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color);

    point = self.points[0];

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);

    for (point in self.points)
    {
        // you'd do your CGContextAddCurveToPoint here; I'm just adding lines
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
    }

    point = [self.points lastObject];
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextClosePath(context);

    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
}
```

Comment: Drawing a single shape with the path was the key to all the problems. I don't know why I was insisting on filling the individual paths. Thanks!